# Need a check for correct english to latin translation(for a tattoo)

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, latin-to-english-translation, translation-check, motto

my mum wanted to get a tattoo and we were trying to figure out the correct translation for it. She wanted a tattoo consisting of different words, like this: "Live. Smile(or live smiling). Believe. Do (aka do it). Dream." ended up with something like "Ridens vive. Crede. Fac. Somnia.". Please let me know if there's a correct translation we could use to express the right meaning, any help is greatly appreciated!~

Answer (score 1):

I think the subjunctive works better here, almost as a series of prayers. Also, leaving verbs without objects (do, believe) sounds very strange to me. I don't know if it would work as a tattoo, but here's my suggestion:

> Subridens vivas.
> In ? credas.
> Quod velis facias.
> De ? somnies.

> May you live smiling.
> May you believe in ?.
> May you do what you want to do.
> May you dream about ?.

I don't know what she actually believes/dreams about, but you should replace the question marks accordingly.